# Modify the tags in windows explorer details pane for folders (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, regedit

I want to add property tags to the details pane for Windows explorer for the folder type. I have successfully done this for file types but cannot achieve this for a folder itself.

To do this for files I have done the following:

1. Open *regedit.exe*
2. Navigate to the registry key: `"HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.*"`, where * is any file extension.
3. Add String value `PreviewDetails` and put properties to display like size: `prop:System.Size`

However I cannot manage this for folders. I also discovered two suspicious keys under **HKCR**, namely: **Folder** and **Directory**. But changing their values like above do nothing even after killing and restarting *explorer.exe*. How do I do this for normal windows folders?